# Can someone explain me this code?, it takes an array and removes the specified numbers in it

Tags: javascript

```
const rm=(arr, ...rem)=>arr.filter(a=>!rem.includes(a))

console.log(rm([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
 // [1,4] is the result of rm.
```

i looked to filter method and the includes method but i am not completely sure how can i use this with confidence

i know how to use the rest parameter, and filter, but then the arrow function appears inside of the filter method, and i dont know why u have `!rem.includes(a)`, like why u have something different that rem (!rem), and then using the same function

Comment: "...rem" gives you array of parameters that you pass after first parameter, in this case is 3 and 2.
!rem.includes(a) is filter function that return item that it is not includes in rem array.

Answer (score 0):

`rm` is a function that expects one or more arguments: One array, and any further values which will be collected in `rem` (the rest parameter).

That means `rem` is an array with a method `includes()`, which returns a boolean value.

Note that accessing properties and calling functions takes [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#precedence_and_associativity) over boolean negation. So we are actually evaluating `rem.includes(a)` first, followed by negating its value: `!( rem.includes(a) )`.

If you are not familiar with operator precedence, then it may be helpful to use parentheses to avoid this disambiguity as shown above, or refer to a [table of operator precedences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table).